# What is the proper way to use data from a grid view before data binding

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that creates a grid view of database records. Each record has a checkbox for deleting the record.

My problem is that the the `page_load` event builds the grid view, then the delete button even fires.  The deleteButton_click event is looping over the gridview looking for checked boxes but never finds any because the 'page_load' event just gave me a clean gridview.  What is the best way to check for checked boxes before the grid view is re-built? Or can I get the checked values without looking at the grid view?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load

    'db calls and other code
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnDelAtt_Click(...) Handles btnDelAtt.Click

    For Each grdRow As GridViewRow In gvFileViewer.Row
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(grdRow.FindControl("cbItem"), CheckBox)
        If chkBox.Checked = True Then 'this is always false thanks to page_load
            'code that does not run
        end if
    next
end sub
```

Comment: !IsPostBack to the page load event?

Comment: ^ that. Make sure your page load event checks for isPostBack before doing things that should only be done once when the page first loads. If Not Page.IsPostBack i believe is the VB syntax

Comment: @Moe unfortunately there are other events on the page that could cause the page to load on post back, i still need the grid view to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, adding !IsPostBack should do it.
You only need to load the grid from the database in the initial call, you don't need to get the data again when post back occurs. You will need to rebind the grid once the delete is over.

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load
        If(!Page.IsPostBack)

            'db calls and other code
            gv.DataBind()

        End Sub

        Protected Sub btnDelAtt_Click(...) Handles btnDelAtt.Click

            For Each grdRow As GridViewRow In gvFileViewer.Row
                Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(grdRow.FindControl("cbItem"), CheckBox)
                //Delete your record
                end if

            next
            //Rebind grid
        end sub
```

Comment: There are several events on the page that will cause it to post back (it's a dynamic form). Will the grid still be there with cached data if i don't bind it every time?

Comment: That's what the view state is for. But since u will rebind the grid after the delete method that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'm (obviously) new to the .net thing and how `viewstate` works, but I'll figure it out. So I should be able to get and bind data in `getAttachments()` when `not isPostBack`, and ignore the gridview again until I need to add/delete a row, Then call `getAttachments()` again when the grid view is expected to change.  Neat. I'll try it in the A.M. and report back! thanks!

Comment: Yes. Let me know if you need more details, would love to help.

Comment: Simplest way to achieve that is to create a method to bind your grid, which will call the database get your data and bind it into the grid. Call this method on initial load (!Page.IsPostBack) and call it again after delete or whenever you need to bind your grid.

Comment: There is actually a function already written, I didn't use it in my pseudo code but it's there.  Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94101/discussion-between-moe-and-travis).